# Python - extract and modify a file path in all files in a directory in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have files .sh files and .json files in which there are file paths given to point to a specific directory, but I should keep on changing the file path, depending on where my python scipt is run.

eg:content of one of my .sh file is 
 "cd /home/aswany/BotStudioInstallation/databricks/platform/databricksastro"

and I should change the file path via python code where the following path

"/home/aswany/BotStudioInstallation/" keep on changing depending on where databicks is located,

I tried the following code:

```
replaceAll(str(self.currentdirectory)+
    "/databricks/platform/devsettings.json",
    "/home/holmes/BotStudioInstallation",self.currentdirectory)
```

and function  replaceAll is:

```
def replaceAll(self,file,searchExp,replaceExp):
     for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
         if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
         sys.stdout.write(line)
```

but above code only replaces a line 
 "`home/holmes/BotStudioInstallation`" to the current directory I am logged in,bt it cannot be sure that "`home/holmes/BotStudioInstallation`" is the only possibility it keep on changing like "`home/aswany/BotStudioInstallation`","`home/dev3/BotStudioInstallation`" etc ,I thought of regular expression for this.

please help me

Comment: Please correct your question a little bit. It's quite difficult to read. Also note that `*.sh` is used for shell scripts and not Python files.

Comment: It is not clear what is your issue. It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096).  Your `replaceAll()` function works as expected (though it wouldn't hurt to specify `backup='.bak'`) but it is likely a wrong approach to solve your actual problem. If all paths should be relative your current directory then remove the base directory part from the paths completely.

Comment: there is a path to a directory specified in a *.sh file and *.json file and i want to identify this path via regular expression and want to replace it with another path which is the current directory of my python code.I want to do this via python scripts. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I 100% understood your issue, but maybe I can help nonetheless.

As pointed out by [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian), you can use relative paths and remove the base part of the path. Using `./databricks/platform/devsettings.json` might be enough. This is by far the most elegant solution.

If for any reason it is not, you can keep the directory you need to access, then append it to the base directory whenever you need it. That should allow you to deal with changes in the base directory. Though in the case the files will be used by other applications than your own, that might not be an option.

```
dir = get_dir_from_json()
dir_with_base = self.currentdirectory + dir
```

Alternatively, not an elegant solution though, without using regex you can use a "pattern" to always replace.

```
{
  "directory": "<<_replace_me_>>/databricks/platform"
}
```

Then you know you can always replace "<<_replace_me_>>" with the base directory.